# How did YouTube know I watched a locally stored file on my computer?

Tags: privacy

I ripped a few videos from YouTube (using y2mate) about a week ago of guitar lessons from a player named John Redbourne in case they disappear. I saved them on my local hard drive in a folder called "Redbourne Guitar" and the files are named after after the songs, like "Salisbury.mp4" etc.

Anyway, I just watched one of the videos off my hard drive, and lo and behold, when I logged into YouTube, my recommended feed was full of John Redbourne videos. I haven't searched or done anything online related to John Redbourne since I downloaded the videos. How did YouTube know I watched it?

Using Windows 10, Firefox, and played video with default "Movies and TV" app that comes with Win 10.

Comment: it's offering you more of the last thing it gave you? not surprising.

Answer (score 3):

YouTube didn't "know" when you played the media from your local hard drive. But it "knew" that you were interested in John Redbourne when you accessed the media on YouTube (in this case, when you downloaded it).

Just a note of caution though, downloading media from YouTube might violate its [terms and conditions](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms).

Comment: Or in other words: correlation (playing a local video correlates with youtube showing similar videos) is not  the same as causation (playing a local video is not the reason that youtube is showing similar  videos). Also anecdotal evidence (two events happened once together) does not mean an actual correlation or even causation.

Answer (score -1):

**YouTube** doesn't know what you watched in your computer that is locally stored file or existing downloaded video. Youtube has very **strong privacy policies** But, they have access to your internet logs and your searched history on the internet is stored in cookies and there might exist a cache file again a specific website.

Youtube has a strong recommendation algorithm that is responsible for your feed and the thing that is recommended for you. This is done based on:

1. searches made across youtube, google and their partner sites.
2. your shopping, carts, and downloads.
3. your interest and recent searches.
4. search volume to a specific location.
5. & there are a lot of other factors.

[(Review youtube privacy policy to know more)](https://www.youtube.com/about/policies/#community-guidelines)

***So, you don't need to worry about that. Just stay calm and enjoy.***

Comment: Strong policies is not what prevents them from seeing what you opened locally on your computer... Technical limitations does that.

Comment: I also don't think that all those factors were necessary for YouTube to recommend a video topic that the user just searched for and viewed a few of just a week ago... Youtube just needs to know what the user viewed on YouTube ...